# how to drag an image by touching in android?

Tags: android

how to drag an image by touching in android?
Please Help me with a sample code.

Comment: does your search button not work?

Comment: possible solution,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404345/getting-the-position-of-an-image-after-drag-in-android

Answer (score 28):

```
package com.examples.Touchmoveimage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class Touchmoveimage extends Activity {

    int windowwidth;
    int windowheight;

    private LayoutParams layoutParams;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        final ImageView balls = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ball);

        balls.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) balls.getLayoutParams();
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                        if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                            x_cord = windowwidth;
                        }
                        if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                            y_cord = windowheight;
                        }

                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;

                        balls.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

works good!!

Comment: worked fine for me :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to read about Gestures especially Scroll - which is drag in Android - and Fling.

I recommend to you [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/) tutorial. Its exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Great as this also introduces some Android Animation stuff like Interpolator.
Source available here: https://code.google.com/p/android-gestures-tutorials/source/checkout

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do drag and drop in Android. You have to write some classes. Look into DragController.java, DragLayer.java in Launcher project.