# getting the position of an image after drag in android

Tags: android, image, drag

hi i need to drag an image in my app and ia m doing that using following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:src="@drawable/csf6a4_flipped"
android:scaleType="matrix" >
</ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

and

```
package com.example.rotatezoommove;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RotateZoomMove extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
private static final String TAG = "Touch";
// These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
      int rotation = 25;
      // Dump touch event to log
      dumpEvent(event);

      // Handle touch events here...
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
         start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
         mode = DRAG;
         break;


      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         if (mode == DRAG) {
            // ...
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                  event.getY() - start.y);
         }
         else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
               matrix.set(savedMatrix);
               float scale = newDist / oldDist;
               matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
         }
         break;
      }

      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
      return true; // indicate event was handled
   }



/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
   private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
            "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int action = event.getAction();
      int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
      sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
      if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
         sb.append("(pid ").append(
               action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
         sb.append(")");
      }
      sb.append("[");
      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
         sb.append("#").append(i);
         sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
         sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
         sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
         if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
      }
      sb.append("]");
      Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
   }

   /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
   private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
      return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
   }

   /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
   private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
      point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
   }
}
```

by using this code i can drag an image successfully but i need get the position of the image after dragging i,e left and top.

i tried event.getX() and event.getY() but i am getting wrong values.

how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Get the `event.getRawX()` and `event.getRawY()` on `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

Answer (score 1):

Implement View.OnDragListener in your acitivity or fragment
override the method

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            // Do nothing
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            //get your drag position here;just use event.getX() and event.getY()
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you want to implement drag and drop ,just 
look at[drag and drop](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html)