# how to set specific path for dragging image in android(so that image can only be dragged in that path)?

Tags: android, image, drag

Look at the code I have adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404345/getting-the-position-of-an-image-after-drag-in-android).

This code has a dragging `image` effect by `Ontouchlistener()`, but it is free to drag  anywhere.  What I want is to drag in a specific path (any circular,linear etc).  Outside that path, `image` shouldn't be dragged.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is it destined for honeycomb and up by any chance?

Comment: it's for Gingerbread and up..

Comment: actually i am building a lock screen application in which a lock icon is to be dragged in curved shape to unlock...

Comment: pre honeycomb drag&drop code is messy (no api).. but it shouldn't be too difficult.. I believe you need to get the x & y of the finger and apply a mathematical algorithm to get a curved shape. (google for an algorithm-the programming language doesn't really matter) but I can think of the basic idea- x=startingPoint+currentDistanceFromStartingPoint . y=startingPoint+currentDistanceFromStartingPoint+curvingFactor .. but that just a rough guess :) .