# Rotating an image around a point by touching and dragging it till the point we want to rotate it

Tags: android

Actually what I want to do is 
I have a Bitmap image I'm using `SurfaceView` instead of View to draw and using `onDraw` function to draw the image.

What I want to do is I have an image a pointer with arrow (like a needle we have in multimeter) 
I want the user to touch the tip of the arrow and rotate if by holding n dragging till the point he wants to rotate it to. ie if arrow is straight then 90 degree on either side we can rotate.

I found few examples on this site and internet but non of them were precise or explained anything and were hard to understand.

If someone can help me with this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You have two things to do.  Detect the touch and then rotate the image.

For the touch stuff you need to use an [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) there are plenty of questions about draging which is the same basic code try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404345/getting-the-position-of-an-image-after-drag-in-android)

Somthing that may help with the [rotate here](http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html) You basicaly use a [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) and use it to transform a [bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).