# how to drag image with finger on my destination point

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to drag an image by touching in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669239/how-to-drag-an-image-by-touching-in-android)

how to moving bitmap left and righ with drag finger with may destination point boundary

ilustration

```
B--------o1-----------o2-----------o3
```

B  = Bitmap

o1 = my destination point one

o2 = my destination point two

o3 = my destination point three

if bitmap drag to righ then bitmap on my destination point one

```
---------B---------o2-----------o3
```

if bitmap on my destination point one drag to right then bitmap change to my destination point two

```
----------o1--------B-------------o3
```

if bitmap on my destination point two drag to left then bitmap back to my destination point one

```
----------B--------o2-------------o3
```

and so on..

how to implement my idea to android code?

please give me sample code because i am newbie on android.

Comment: I think you're expecting [this](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-iii,823.html)

Comment: @SpK +1 nice tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/vg"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DragActivity:

```
public class DragActivity extends Activity {

    private View selected_item = null;
    private int offset_x = 0;
    private int offset_y = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag);
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.vg);
    vg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            switch(event.getActionMasked())
                            {
                                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                            int x = (int)event.getX() - offset_x;
                                            int y = (int)event.getY() - offset_y;
                    int w = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()- 70;
                    int h = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()- 70;
                    if(x > w)
                        x = w;
                    if(y > h)
                        y = h;
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                     lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
                                            selected_item.setLayoutParams(lp);
                                            break;
                                    default:
                                            break;
                            }
                            return true;
                    }
});
   ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            switch(event.getActionMasked())
                            {
                                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                            offset_x = (int)event.getX();
                                            offset_y = (int)event.getY();
                                            selected_item = v;
                                            break;
                                    default:
                                            break;
                            }

                            return false;
                    }
            });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [this tutorial](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-iii,823.html) By use of `onTouchEvent` will give you whatever you want as per that example tutorial link. Sample code -

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mX = (int) event.getX() - mBitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    mY = (int) event.getY() - mBitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```