# how to drag an imageview in an android application using touch

Tags: android, imageview, drag

I'd like to create an app where i drag a bottle of water into the mouth of a character on the screen, similar to the android app Pou. I'm interested in knowing what would be the best way of doing that.

Thank you.

Comment: this post look similar.have a look.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669239/how-to-drag-an-image-by-touching-in-android

Keep Coding! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this post look similar.have a look. 
[how to drag an image by touching in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669239/how-to-drag-an-image-by-touching-in-android)
Keep Coding! :)