# Is there a way to restrict the motion of an image view while dragging?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to drag an imageview along a line. The line is  preferably another imageView.

Is there a way that this can be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3854371/1848929