# Moving an image inside in other frame image android

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-image

I have a frame image and another image selected from gallery. What i want is to place that image inside the transparent part of that frame image and also I can apply onTouchListener on the image selected from gallery.
Like in the app whose link is provided following.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lyrebirdstudio.pipcamera

Any idea or concept will be helpful.
My IDEA
Here is what i am thinking to create a relative layout and setting the Picture Frame as a background and then scaling the other image according to the size of the relative layout. Then i can apply onTouchlistener on the image easily.
Am i going in right direction or there is some better way though which i can achieve the desire results?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-drag-a-view-in-android

OR

[how to drag an image by touching in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669239/how-to-drag-an-image-by-touching-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top)
hope it helps..

Comment: yup it sure can help me but my main problem is how to set an image from a gallery inside a transparent part of a frame image?

Comment: you can do it with first option which suggested... take a image from gallery on initialization of activity. And also if you want change background image then take it from  gallery and set it to Relative layout background.

Comment: Well i have to keep in check this factor that only transparent part of the Frame image is filled and image selected from gallery only set in that transparet part